# Check if class has a variable in its constructor based on a string?

Tags: java

Let's say I have a class named `Person` and its constructor had variables like `name`, `age`, `hairColor` and so on. If I had a function that receives a string that should match one of the class's variables, how could I check if that class actually had that variable and how could I go about modifying it? For example:

```
public class Person {
    public String name;
    public int age;
    public String hairColor;

    public Person() {
        name = "Bryce";
        age = 21;
        hairColor = "brown";
    }

    public void changeHairColor(String variable, String color) {
        if (/*this class contains the variable passed as an argument to this method*/) {
            // Person[variable] = color
        }
    }
}
```

I'm a python dev, mostly, so the method `changeHairColor` has some pseudo-python in it. I want to be able to edit the variable in a similar way you could edit variables inside of dictionaries with Python:

```
person = {
    "name": "Bryce",
    "age": 21,
    "hairColor": "brown"
}

def changeHairColor(variable, color):
    person[variable] = color
```

If that is at all possible.

Comment: Welcome to statically typed languages! Enjoy your stay. PS: You can't do that without using *reflection*. But you don't have to ! You can make a switch statement on the variable name and update the object accordingly.

Comment: What would you actually need this for? The person example seems a bit contrived. If you need a key-value store, you can use a `Map<K,V>`.

Comment: Don't bend the tool at hand so much. While this is possible, it's needlessly complicated and not idiomatic, that is, other people will have hard time understanding why such a thing is done. Consider other approaches. (For that, it's worth stating the problem you're solving.)

Comment: I'm creating an RPG plugin out of the Bukkit API for Minecraft. In my project, I have a `PlayerCharacter` class that stores player attribute modifiers. The method `levelUp` inside of the class takes arguments that target what skill the player wants to level, and by how much. Right now, I have a long chain of `else if` statements that checks if the string argument matches a variable: `if (arg == "vitality")` and then applies the amount specified to the attribute: `vitality += amt`. However, there are quite a few skills, so this gets a bit redundant. Was just seeing if there was a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not solve this with reflection. If your `PlayerCharacter` has an enumerable set of attributes, I would model these as a Java `enum` and store the attribute values within the `PlayerCharacter` object in an `EnumMap`:

```
import java.util.EnumMap;

public class PlayerCharacter {

    public enum Attribute {
        AGILITY,
        DEXTERITY,
        /* etc ...*/
        VITALITY
    }

    private EnumMap<Attribute, Integer> attributes = new EnumMap<>(Attribute.class);

    public PlayerCharacter() {
        // initialize each attribute with a default value (0 in this example)
        for (Attribute a : Attribute.values()) {
            attributes.put(a, new Integer(0));
        }
    }

    public int getValue(Attribute attribute) {
       return attributes.get(attribute);
    }

    public void levelUp(Attribute attribute, int amount) {
        attributes.put(attribute, attributes.get(attribute) + amount);
    }
}
```

The biggest benefit of using an `enum` instead of plain old `String` (+reflection), is that this way you get compile-time type safety for the code that's using your `PlayerCharacter`.

Comment: You missed the crucial part: something like `int getValue(String attr_name)` that uses `Attribute.valueOf(attr_name)` to look up the the enum value by string value. Bonus points for proper handling of `IllegalArgumentException` and logging the bad attribute name. Add it, and I'll upvote your answer.

Comment: Adding `int getValue(String attr_name)` would defeat the purpose of using an `enum` in the first place: Client code would no longer get proper checks compile-time but would need to prepare to catch an `IllegalArgumentException` run-time. Clients that don't want compile-time safety can already do something like `getValue(Attribute.valueOf(attr_name))` themselves.

Comment: @mick-nemonic: (1) It will solve the OP's actual problem, which is access to a value by a name only known at runtime, using a String from a network API, and (2) would still allow to use proper enums _everywhere else,_ enjoying the compile-time safety checks.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to do it in Java is to use [Java Reflection API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/):

```
public class Test {
    public String name;
    public int age;
    public String hairColor;

    public void setProperty(String property, Object value) {
        try {
            Field declaredField = this.getClass().getDeclaredField(property);
            switch (declaredField.getAnnotatedType().getType().getTypeName()) {
                case "java.lang.String":
                    declaredField.set(this, value);
                    break;
                // handle other types
            }
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            // handle exception
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // handle exception
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.setProperty("name", "Bob");
        System.out.println(test.name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Reflection API, you can access the methods and properties on an object at run time. The other answer describes its usage. But I don't recommend reflections for your problem. How about the following:

```
   public void changeHairColor(String variable, String color) {
       if("name".equalsIgnoreCase(variable))
           this.name = color;
       else if("age".equalsIgnoreCase(variable))
           this.age = Integer.parseInt(color);
       else if("color".equalsIgnoreCase(variable))
            this.color = color;
       else
           throw new Exception ("error - property not available"); 
      }
   }
```

Note, your existing method name 'changeHairColor' doesn't make sense in the context. It should be someething like 'changeProperty' because you are not just changing the 'color', you are changing any available property with this method.